# How to programatically create availability calendars for each node?

Tags: nodes, entities, datetime

I'm working on a booking page on which I need to programatically add an availability calendar for each property element (node).

All the data come from external sources and is imported programatically. We have to store the availability of the properties locally and import this information from an xml that is provided to us periodically.

We are using the [Availability Calendars](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) module (7.x-5.4) and I have the functions to create the availability calendars which is provided in `availability_calendar.inc`, which is:

```
availability_calendar_create_calendar()
```

I've also the function that would allow me to fill the calendar with the availability data that I get from the xml file:

```
availability_calendar_update_multiple_availability($cid, $changes)
```

But I can't see how I can relate this information with the corresponding node. I use the entities API but I'm not sure which parameters I should pass to the calendar field and how to pass them.

I thought about:

```
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $raw_node);
$entity->field_calendar->set( array(
                          'enabled' => 1,
                          'name' => $nodetitle,
                          'cid' => $cid,
                          ));
$entity->revision->set(1);
return $entity->save();
```

But I didn't find it in the documentation and I don't want to start trying things blindly.

Any advice will be welcome!

**Edit**:

It works exactly as it is described in this post, so solved!

Comment: I think you should re-edit your self deleted answer, and include a summary of what exactly you mean with that "it works exactly as it is described in this post" (but don't include the question related parts of your question, only the answer part of it). Then undelete your own answer, and mark it as "accepted". Just a suggestion ...